# JIRA JQL Contains Hyphen

Tags: jira, jql

I'm created tickets with titles (summaries?) as follows:

```
ABC - My Ticket Title
ABC - Title 2
```

I'm trying to create a filter which shows any summary which starts with `ABC -`

The following don't work:

```
summary ~ "ABC - "
summary ~ "ABC \- "
summary ~ "ABC \\- "
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There is an open ticket to Atlassian for this bug: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-66244

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate this was posted a while ago but, You should be able to replace summary with the word text which should work, Below is what I tend to use when I want to do a wild card search when I only know the start of a summary.

```
text ~ "ABC*"
```

Comment: Please consider formatting it as `text ~ "ABC*"`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's really weird, but you should search as following:

```
summary ~ 'ABC >'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`summary ~ "\"ABC - \""`

Based on ["searching for an exact phrase"](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/Search-for-an-exact-phrase-with-JQL/ba-p/2131545)

> ### Search for an exact phrase with JQL
>
> #### Sep 26, 2022
>
> Advanced search lets
> you search for issues by building structured queries using the Jira
> Query Language (JQL). It's being updated to provide more accurate
> results when searching for an exact phrase.
>
> For example, if you enter **summary ~ "\"saturn summer sizzle\""** as a
> JQL query, the search results will only include issues where the
> summary contains the exact phrase "saturn summer sizzle".